# How to use setTransformHint with IGraphicBufferProducer?

Tags: android, native

I would like to be able to apply transformation to graphic data present in a `IGraphicBufferProducer`.

This interface was previously called `ISurfaceTexture` in Android previous release (since 4.2 I believe) and it seems it was possible to call directly `setTransformHint` to apply such transformation.

I would like to do that call for `IGraphicBufferProducer` but it doesn't seem to be possible anymore.

In fact I would like to do a 90° rotation to graphic data present in buffers.

Do you know how this would be possible ?

Thanks.